# Button error, but I get IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

I have two buttons on my interface. I want both of them to be able to call their respective functions when I either click on them or a hit the `Enter Key`.
The problem I'm having is that only the last button in the traveral **focus** gets activated when I hit the `Enter Key`, even if the preceeding one has the **focus**. What can I do to resolve this problem.
Useful answer are welcome and appreciated.

This is the problem in question:

```
from tkinter import *

w = Tk()

def startProgram(event = None):
    print('Program Starting')

def readyContent(event = None):
    print('Content being prepared')

# Buttons
Button(text='Prepare', command=readyContent).grid(row=10,column=2)
w.bind('<Return>',readyContent) # Binds the Return key to a Function
Button(text='Start', command=startProgram).grid(row=10,column=3)
w.bind('<Return>',startProgram) # Binds the Return key to a Function

w.mainloop()
```

When you click on the **Prepare** or **Start** button, in return you get either **Content being prepared** or **Program Starting** repectively. Nothing like that happens when you use the `Tab Key` to give **focus** to one button or the other. Even if the **focus** is on the **Prepare** button, when you hit `Enter` you get: **Program Starting**

Comment: Which button has focus is completely irrelevant here, since you didn't bind anything to the individual buttons.

Comment: Please include the full traceback of your error, so we can determine which line is the issue

Comment: @jasonharper - thanks to both for the input. I am new at Tkinter. I thought I had to bind the function to the window. In another project, I only had one button and I guess that's why this formula worked without a hitch. The panorama changed when I had to deal with to buttons. Thanks for you comment. I'm going to post the solution in case anyone has the same problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to my problem. 
I hope it helps anyone else having the same problem as me.

```
from tkinter import *

w = Tk()

def startProgram(event = None):
    print('Program Starting')

def readyContent(event = None):
    print('Content being prepared')

# Buttons
btn1 = Button(text='Prepare', command=readyContent)
btn1.grid(row=10,column=2)
btn1.bind('<Return>',readyContent) # Binds the Return key to a Function
btn2 = Button(text='Start', command=startProgram)
btn2.grid(row=10,column=3)
btn2.bind('<Return>',startProgram) # Binds the Return key to a Function

w.mainloop()
```

Have a good day!  :)